ghostarchive: search vs "vidsearch"
Trying to figure out why search sometimes doesn't work on ghostarchive.
Eg if I search for google.com/search?q=zem it works, but if I search for google.com/search?q=zemp it redirects to
../vidsearch?q=..
from
../search?term=..
causing a 502 cloudflare (has accurate timelog).
Any ideas why?
Any ideas how to search for eg google.com/search?q=zemp   ?
